# Move a div within another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a simple app.

When we **drag** the **small box** inside the **bigger box**, the **smaller box** should move inside the **bigger box**.

However, it **can't go outside the bigger box.** I know how to move the smaller box, but I don't know how to keep it inside the bigger box. Can somebody help me, please?

As I mentioned, my code moves the small box properly but does not keep it inside the bigger box.

```js
var guy=document.getElementById("guy");
var cont=document.getElementById("container");
var lastX,lastY; // Tracks the last observed mouse X and Y position


guy.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 1) {
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
      addEventListener("mousemove", moved);
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent selection
    }
  });

function buttonPressed(event) {
    if (event.buttons == null)
      return event.which != 0;
    else
      return event.buttons != 0;
  }
  function moved(event) {
    if (!buttonPressed(event)) {
      removeEventListener("mousemove", moved);
    } else {
      var distX = event.pageX - lastX;
      var distY = event.pageY - lastY;    
      guy.style.left =guy.offsetLeft + distX  + "px";
      guy.style.top = guy.offsetTop + distY  + "px";
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
    }
  }
```

```css
#container {
height:400px;
width:600px;
outline: 1px solid black;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top: 0px;
background-color:green;
}
#guy {
position:absolute;
height:50px;
width:50px;
outline: 1px solid black;
background-color:red;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" draggable="true" ></div>
<div id="guy"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to restrict guy's position to the container's bounds. In other words, guy's `x` position can at minimum be the container's `x` position, at maximum the container's `x` position plus the container's `width` minus guy's `witdh`. The same goes for the `y` axis, but with `height` instead of `width`.

```js
var guy=document.getElementById("guy");
var cont=document.getElementById("container");
var lastX,lastY; // Tracks the last observed mouse X and Y position

var minX = cont.offsetLeft;
var maxX = minX + cont.offsetWidth - guy.offsetWidth;

var minY = cont.offsetTop;
var maxY = minY + cont.offsetHeight - guy.offsetHeight;

guy.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 1) {
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
      addEventListener("mousemove", moved);
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent selection
    }
  });

function buttonPressed(event) {
    if (event.buttons == null)
      return event.which != 0;
    else
      return event.buttons != 0;
  }
  function moved(event) {
    if (!buttonPressed(event)) {
      removeEventListener("mousemove", moved);
    } else {
      var distX = event.pageX - lastX;
      var distY = event.pageY - lastY;
      
      var targetX = guy.offsetLeft + distX;
      var targetY = guy.offsetTop + distY;
      
      guy.style.left = Math.min(maxX, Math.max(minX, targetX)) + "px";
      guy.style.top = Math.min(maxY, Math.max(minY, targetY)) + "px";
      
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
    }
  }
```

```css
#container {
height:200px;
width:300px;
outline: 1px solid black;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top: 0px;
background-color:green;
}
#guy {
position:absolute;
height:50px;
width:50px;
outline: 1px solid black;
background-color:red;
left: 100px;
top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" draggable="true" ></div>
<div id="guy"></div>
```

Comment: this, except I'd calculate the minX, minY, and the constant part of maxX and maxY on page load instead of inside the event

Comment: @MikeFurlender You are absolutely right, I've pulled it out of the event handler. Good catch.